# Error: Imported Xml content can not be parsed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape the expected arrival times of a flight and put it into a Google Sheets cell in a way that it will auto-refresh if the flight gets delayed or is expected to arrive early. I am using this website for the data, here's an example flight:

[Flight Tracker]
https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL1316

(Note: I am just trying to put the expected arrival time in one cell i.e: 04:19PM EDT, I don't need any of the other info)

I tried using the IMPORTXML feature with the following formula

=IMPORTXML("https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL1316", "//*[starts-with(@id='flightPageTourStep1')/div[3]/div[2]/span[3]/em')")
It says loading then #N/A and then returns the following error:

-Error Imported Xml content can not be parsed.

Any help or input on how to do this successfully would be greatly appreciated

[Attached is a screenshot of the website elements in case it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW1cM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When I saw the URL, it seems that the value is created by Javascript. So, unfortunately, `IMPORTXML` cannot be used for retrieving your expected value. But, fortunately, when I saw HTML data, I noticed that your expected value is included in the HTML as JSON data. So in this answer, I would like to propose to use Google Apps Script for retrieving your expected value.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save the script.

```js
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const str = res.getContentText().match(/var trackpollBootstrap \=(.+?);<\/script>/);
  if (str && str.length > 1) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(str[1].trim());
    const k = Object.keys(obj.flights)[0];
    return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(obj.flights[k].gateArrivalTimes.estimated * 1000), "America/New_York", "hh:mma 'EDT'");
  }
  return "Value was not found.";
}
```

- When this script is used, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE("https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL1316")` to a cell. By this, the script is run.
- In this sample script, in order to match the result value to your provided image, the value is returned as the string value. But, if you want to retrieve the value as the date object. Please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(obj.flights[k].gateArrivalTimes.estimated * 1000), "America/New_York", "hh:mma 'EDT'");
    ```
  - To

    ```
      return new Date(obj.flights[k].gateArrivalTimes.estimated * 1000);
    ```

#### Testing:

When this script is used for your URL, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided URL of `https://flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL1316`. So, when you change the URL, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)